# Error while using SignalR in Android Studio

Tags: android, signalr

I'm using SingnalR with code bellow

```
implementation files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
implementation files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
```

I added 'jar' files in my 'libs' folder.
when I'm using 'Generate Signed APK' everything is OK.

But when I'm using '**Generate Android App Bundle**' i get this Error :
File 'root/lib/getLibs.sh' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.

Please help how to solve it
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The library folder name should be "libs" not "lib". Hopefully it will resolve the issue.

To do this, open the SinglaR JAR using WinRAR (or any other zip) and rename lib folder to libs.

Comment: I know that . it was a Typographical mistake

Answer (score 0):

Use this updated implementation for android from microsoft :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#connect-to-a-hub

Or if you want to make realtime app, you can use firebase and configure it from server using asp.net